# MySql error that I can't replicate on update query

Tags: mysql

Sometimes, not always I receive the following error:

> ## 1040 - Column 'avg_visit_duration' cannot be null

on the following query

```
UPDATE `visitors_stats` SET avg_visit_duration = if( avg_visit_duration =0, 41371, round( (
avg_visit_duration * ( visitors_number -1 ) +41371 ) / visitors_number, 2 )
),
max_visit_duration = if( 41371 > max_visit_duration, 41371, max_visit_duration ) ,
min_visit_duration = if( min_visit_duration =0, 41371, if( 41371 < min_visit_duration, 41371, min_visit_duration ) ) WHERE memberid = "74e57e4027c250edc9f1c4d38136d935" AND `date` = "2016-10-27"
```

The problem is that if I go and put this query in phpmyadmin it returns `1 row affected` or `0 row affected`

I've tried many combinations with an empty table, with a future date, with a date from the past. no errors are returned.

But every day when I check the log on my program I see 3-4 of this errors, which is not much , because there are executed around 3-4k similar queries like this / day.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors_stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `memberid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `visitors_number` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `avg_visit_duration` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `max_visit_duration` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `min_visit_duration` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `date` (`date`,`memberid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What could be the problem?

UPDATE: Many answered that the problem might be from

```
round((avg_visit_duration * ( visitors_number -1 ) +41371 ) / visitors_number, 2 ))
```

but visitors_number is always 0 when avg_visit_duration=0 which is fixed by the if condition

```
if( avg_visit_duration =0, 41371, round( ...
```

However I forced the table to simulate the situation when visitors_number=0 and I receive a different error:

> ## 1365 - Division by 0

which is different from my initial error:

> ## 1040 - Column 'avg_visit_duration' cannot be null

Comment: please get into the habit of using upper case letters for SQL keywords and lower case letters for table and column names. It makes your queries a lot more readable. you seem to have done so already in your create statement

Answer (score 1):

You are using:

`(avg_visit_duration*(visitors_number-1)+41371)/visitors_number`

This will rise error when you have visitors_number=0 and the values for `avg_visit_duration` will not be calculated.

Comment: thanks for you comment. that's why I have if( avg_visit_duration =0 ... meaning that visitors_number=0

Comment: it would be safer to check directly for `visitors_number=0` instead of `avg_visit_duration=0`, just in case there are records with this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [latest documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html):

> All mathematical functions return NULL in the event of an error.

What this means is that if your `round()` fails for whatever reason, it will be a null value.

If `visitors_number` is 0, then you are effectively trying to divide by 0 (a big no no) and it will throw an error.